# Using Ant with FlexBuilder

Tags: apache-flex, ant, flexbuilder

I need to run some precompile steps before I build my project using FlexBuilder. I assume I will need to use Ant to do this. Any tutorials that anyone knows of that can help me along my path? I know next to nothing about Ant and Eclipse (FlexBuilder).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use solely use ant to build all my Flex applications. I wrote a tutorial on how to set up Flex / Ant in a Linux environment, but much can be translated to windows:

http://blog.apterainc.com/software/setting-up-a-flex-development-enviroment-in-gnulinux/

This link is the Adobe's instructions on how to use ant tasks with Flex (everything from installing to compiling your first Flex application):

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=anttasks_1.html

If you run into any problems, post them here and I will help resolve them.